# How to force download of css swf before page load in adobe flex?

Tags: flex4

I have a compiled css file (swf) which I am loading in my preintialize phase of my spark application in adobe flex 4.1.
I have observed that for every user, the first time, the page loads without any css and in a second or two the CSS loads and there is a flicker.
I understand that it takes time to download the swf from server and hence, the flicker appears. After this, the browser caches the same and hence we don't face this on other views.
Could anyone please suggest how can I avoid this flicker? How can I enforce the swf to be cached first and then load the page?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this. It has 2 steps:

1. Prefetch the css swf file in html before running the flex application swf made the css available in cache before the app loaded. It removed the flicker.
2. The css swf file was trying to reach out to crossdomain.xml CDNs of adobe which were blocked by my firewall. As a solution, I set static-link-runtime-shared-libraries to true in my mxmlc compiler arguments. It made my css swf file a bit larger, but now it does not lookup adobe CDNs anymore.